# How to pass variables in page from a php script to another php script without using 'global'?

Tags: php, session-variables

maybe this is a strange problem. This is not about passing values from one page to another.

I've got one page. It includes scriptA and scriptB.

Script A is executed by java script via ajax, and should set a variable that is to be then used by script B. I cannot write it in html, and cannot persist it in js, nor using a global php variable, I think, in this case. Also, I'm not reloading the page (because first script is called via ajax).

So would it be good to use sessions here, even if I'm not passing the variable from one page to another? Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: use sessions is better. because you can use session anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with session variables or cookies. It´s better to use session variables because you can use them anywhere in your website.

Regards.

Comment: Ok I used sessions. Still, I'm not a security dragon.. So, is it safe to store data that should be secret in sessions? In my case I'm storing the name of a directory where I save files uploaded via form. Only the directory name, not the entire path, though. The directory name changes for each session and is randomly generated. Still, could someone maybe guess it within a session?

Comment: I think that cannot happen if you have the correct permission to those folders. @Stratboy

Comment: And what should they be? :) I'm not exactly a unix guy :)

Comment: I think 644 or 755

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways off the top of my head (except sessions):

1. Include ScriptB into ScriptA

ScriptA.php

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST['myVar'];
    include "ScriptB.php";
```

ScriptB.php

```
<?php
    echo $a;
```

2. Return a value from ScriptA.php which you can then send to ScriptB.php

ScriptA.php

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['myVar'];

echo json_encode(['data' => $a]);
```

ajax.js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./ScriptA.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  succes: function (response) {
    let json = JSON.parse(response);
    let myVar = json.data;

    $.ajax({
      url: "./ScriptB.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {data: myVar},
      dataType: "JSON"
    })

  }
})
```